# Issue with Java 1.5 on RHEL 8

Tags: java, redhat

I am facing an issue trying to see java version on a server that has as an OS RHEL 8. The java version is 1.5.
`/usr/java/java/jdk1.5.0_11/bin/java -version`

The response I get back is:

> There was an error trying to initialize the HPI library.
> Please check your installation, HotSpot does not work correctly when
> installed in the JDK 1.2 Linux Production Release, or with any JDK
> 1.1.x release.
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Does anyone have an idea?
I want to start an old app that can not run with newer java version.

So far I have tried:

- Installing different java 1.5 version from a .bin file
- Checked the file permissions (user, execution, etc...)
- Install a more recent java 1.5 from an .rpm file

Comment: Most likely there is an incompatibility between the system libraries like libc and the java binary. Linux doesn't really support long-term binary compatibility. You could try a VM/container/chroot with some older Linux distro to give java the environment it wants. The java release seems to be 2007-ish, so something from that era.

Answer (score 4):

RHEL 8 was released in 2019. Java 1.5 in 2004. It should be expected that it is not supported by a more recent operating system. Also it is a crazy security risk to use Java 1.5 on this decade. Either use a current version of Java/OpenJDK or do as @teapot418 says and use a Virtual Machine of an older operating system (which could be its own risk). If there is an incompatibility of your software with newer JDKs you could try JDK 8, which is the nearest release still supported by some OpenJDK distributions.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the assistance and your thoughts. I managed to set it up by installing libnsl with dnf and then install java 1.5 from oracle .rpm file

Comment: I'm not sure that answers are the right place to thank other user for their post. Maybe you could double  check    https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-guidelines , Closing session in particular

Comment: Guidelines not respected